# for both of which

Tags: expressions, prepositions

Is it correct to use "for both of which.."?

I would like to write something like:

"We have developed two methods to solve the problem, for both of which a patent application has been filed with Company X."

Is this correct? If not, how would you re-write it?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The relative phrase is "for both of which", where it is just "which" that is anaphoric to "problem".

Comment: But I mean two patents for the two methods.

Comment: "Which" is of course anaphoric to "methods". Apologies!

Comment: Strictly, you need "for each of which". Strictly, what you posted suggests one application is meant to cover the two processes… and apart from the Patent Office, who will mind, please?